# Logging in sharepoint 2010 in one central place?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

How to log all sharepoint errors, workflow errors, custom code errors into one central place?

is it even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SharePoint uses the ULS logs to do this. Have a look at the [ULS Log Viewer](http://ulsviewer.codeplex.com/)  for a utility that lets you easily view them. Also, you can write to the ULS logs in you custom code for any tracing you might wish to do.

The settings for what SharePoint is going to log to the ULS (trace log) and Event Log can be found in Central Administration: Monitoring - Configure diagnostic logging (http://xxxxxxx/_admin/metrics.aspx). This page also allows you to configure where the logs are stored. Note that in a farm, each server will have its own logs. You need to take this into consideration when diagnosing a problem.

The logs are written by the Windows Service 'SharePoint 2010 Tracing'. Often times when a user encounters an error in the SharePoint UI, they are given a 'Correlation ID' in the error message. This is a guid that can be searched for in the ULS logs. Note that this guid can take a few minutes to show up in the logs.

Comment: but all logs are enabled by default, where can I see and enable/disable events.

Answer (score 2):

If you are developer then you can leverage to write all errors to ULS Logs ( where SP writes for all OOTB features )

http://sharepointnadeem.blogspot.com/2011/10/sharepoint-2010-diagnostic-logging.html